# How dangerous is it to store JSON data in a database?

Tags: javascript, security, json, xss

I need a mechanism for storing complex data structures created in client side javascript. I've been considering using the [stringify](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) method to convert the javascript object into a string, store it in the database and then pull it back out and use the reverse parse method to give me the javascript object back.

Is this just a bad idea or can it be done safely? If it can, what are some pitfalls I should be sure to avoid? Or should I just come up with my own method for accomplishing this?

Comment: Not sure what form of database you've got access to from javascript. But I get all kinds of "I have a bad feeling about this" when a web application's javascript gets so complex it needs a database...

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. Unfortunately I'm 100% sure we don't know all the pieces of data we'll be needing to store necessitating some kind of flexible data storage method which rules out strict fields and tables. And I'm 90% sure I'll never have to query this data.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's fine so long as you don't deserialize using `eval`.

Comment: Chosen as answer simply because it's probably one of the more important points to remember.

Answer (score 9):

It can be done and I've done it. It's as safe as your database.

The only downside is it's practically impossible to use the stored data in queries. Down the track you may come to wish you'd stored the data as table fields to enable filtering and sorting etc.

Since the data is user created make sure you're using a safe method to insert the data to protect yourself from injection attacks (don't just blindly concatenate the data into a query string).

Comment: +1 for pointing out the horrible, horrible violation of just about any kind of normal form... but sometimes what must be done must be done :-/

Comment: Why would it be a violation of the normal form? If you're using it to save a state of an app, so you're not actually using it to store data, but to store a session-state (like a hybernation/sleep for an OS is), why would it be wrong? I agree that it CAN be a bit of a hack, but no need to assume that straight away, is there?.. Nothing wrong with the answer though...

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a database it means you need a serverside language to communicate with the database. Any data you have is easily converted from and to json with most serverside languages.

I can't imagine a proper usecase unless you have a sh*tload of javascript, it needs to be very performant, and you have exhausted all other possibilities such as caching, query optimization, etc...

An other downside of doing this is that you can't easily query the data in your database which is always nice when you want to get any kind of reporting done.
And what if your json structure changes? Will you update all the scripts in your database? Or will you force yourself to cope with the changes in the parsing code?

**Conclusion**

Imho it is not dangerous to do so but it leaves little room for manageability and future updates.

Comment: The use case is the project will continually require new pages be added with widely different functionalities and pieces of data at least four times per week. I cannot predict all the pieces of data that need to be stored and recompiling and redeploying the project four times per week from now until doomsday doesn't sound like a good idea either. By placing most of the functionality code on the client side of things these pages can be added and altered "on the fly".

Comment: You've got a good point and it immediately invalidates all my arguments. Sounds like an exciting scenario :-)

Comment: Thanks. I was in coding mode when I posted my earlier comment and looking at it now I don't think I conveyed the tone I intended. Apologies if it came of rude somehow. :) I appreciated your input!

Comment: No apologies necessary mate! It's completely fair.